# I have created two classes, when I entered negative quantity and negative price it does not set to be "0" and "0.0"

Tags: java, invoice

I have created two classes, when I entered negative quantity and negative price it does not set to be "0" and "0.0" respectively as I assigned condition in  **setitmprch(int itmprch)** and **setitmprch(int itmprch)** methods. Kindly tell where I did a mistake.

```
public class INVOICE {
private String pn;
private String pdscp;
private int itmprch;
private double prpitm;
private double amount;


public INVOICE(String pn, String pdscp, int itmprch, double prpitm ){
    this.pn=pn;
    this.pdscp=pdscp;
    this.itmprch=itmprch;
    this.prpitm=prpitm;

}

public void setpn(String pn){
    this.pn=pn;
}
public void setpdscp(String pdscp){
    this.pdscp=pdscp;
   }

public void setitmprch(int itmprch){
    if (itmprch < 0)
        itmprch=0;
}
public void setprpitm(double prpitm){
   if(prpitm > 0.0)
       this.prpitm=prpitm;
   else if(prpitm < 0.0)
       this.prpitm=0.0;
}

public String getpn(){
return pn;
}

public String getpdscp(){
return pdscp;
}
public int getitmprch(){
return itmprch;
}
public double getprpitm(){
return prpitm;
}
public double getInvoiceAmount(){
amount= getitmprch()*getprpitm();
return amount; 
}
}

   public class INVOICETEST {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
INVOICE in= new INVOICE("Mercedez","Arw 777",-3,-2.0);

System.out.printf("Part number is: %s\n",in.getpn());
System.out.printf("Part decription is: %s\n", in.getpdscp());    
System.out.printf("Item purchased: %s\n",in.getitmprch());
System.out.printf("Price per item is: %s\n",in.getprpitm());
System.out.printf("Total amount is: %s\n",in.getInvoiceAmount());


}

}
```

Comment: Brother, please _never_ get into the habit of using `double` to store an amount of money.  As soon as you start adding, subtracting and multiplying `double` values, you're going to start losing accuracy.  Except for a few quite specialised cases, you should use `BigDecimal` to store money with.  It's a bit more awkward at first, but you'll manage to avoid frustrating "floating point precision" problems.

Comment: yes dear I am a beginner  I do not have a concept of  **BigDecimal** that's why I use **double** values.

Comment: I can tell that you're a beginner, and that's why I'm giving you advice.  Do _not_ get into the habit of using `double` for money.  Try to learn to use `BigDecimal` instead.

Comment: Dear, I appreciate your advice. I will try to learn the concept of **BigDecimal**.

Comment: Or better than `BigDouble` - at least in some cases - is to use an integer type, e.g. in the use represent an integer number of cents rather than a fractional number of dollars. There are whole posts on the pros and cons of these methods.

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning values to the method parameters, which will be lost as soon as you exit your method. Add `this.itmprch = itmprch` to your `setitmprch` method. Also have a look at some Java programming guidelines to improve code readability.

```
public void setitmprch(int itmprch){
    if (itmprch < 0)
        itmprch=0;
    this.itmprch = itmprch;
}
```

Also your constructor should call the setter methods instead of assign values directly. It would look something like this:

```
public INVOICE(String pn, String pdscp, int itmprch, double prpitm ){
    setpn(pn);
    setpdscp(pdscp);
    setitmprch(itmprch);
    setprpitm(prpitm);
}
```

Comment: Same for `setprpitm`, there is no attribution if the parameter is 0.0, there is no need for a second condition to check for negative value, everything that is not positive number follow the same logic -> `= 0`,

Comment: Again I correct it and added **this.itmprch=itmprch** in *setitmprch* and **this.prpitm=prpitm** in *setprpitm* but still same problem occurred.

Comment: @MohammadUmer Your constructor should call the setter methods instead of assigning directly to the variables, I did not see that at first glance and will edit it into my answer.

Comment: @MohammadUmer call the set### in the constructor instead of assign the variable directly,  you are overriding the condition defined in the setters.

Comment: Calling setter methods in the constructor is good practice, because in the rare case (which you have here) where the setter methods contain logic, that logic is executed and not bypassed. This is Java, here a simple assignment `x=2` does not execute the setter method. The other part should be explained in my answer.

Comment: @MohammadUmer Glad the solution worked. Would you mind accepting this answer? It might help people
experiencing a similar issue and will help getting your question noticed. For more
information, take a look at our [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use all caps for class names.

Use more descriptive variable names - my eyes are bleeding looking at this and it takes 10x longer to understand than it should.

Use automatic properties rather than having private backing fields and void methods to set/get.

Use property for simple calculations such as working out invoice amount.

Don't asssign to private variable then return said variable.

Use unit tests to test your logic rather than a main method. What happens when your code grows, how are you going to test it all using one entry point?

Don't use protected keywords like `in` for variable names (in your main function).

The following code is in C#, but it should be easily transcribable to Java. Do some research on unit testing frameworks for Java and try and incorporate that into your workflow.

```
public class Invoice
{
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public double InvoiceAmount => Price * Amount;
}

[TestClass]
public class InvoiceTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestInvoiceAmount()
    {
        // Arrange
        var testInvoice = new Invoice()
        {
            ModelName = "Audi R8",
            Price = 5000.0,
            Amount = 1
        };

        // Act
        double invoiceAmount = testInvoice.InvoiceAmount;

        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(invoiceAmount == 5000.0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are messing with language here ;-) But the syntax notes are needed.

Comment: Yea, I mean the problem in the question is more "general coding style and good practice" than language specific. But point taken, edited my answer.

Comment: Well, the problem in your edit is that the mistake are coming from the logic in the setters. There is condition to follow, which are not done in your version, so this doesn't answer the question, you removed the problem changing the result

Comment: I feel this is a poor answer.  OP asked where his mistake was - and the correct answer is that `setItmPrch` never set any values, and that the constructor doesn't have the logic to strip out negative values.  This answer contains an awful lot of very good advice, plus a veritable shoal of red herrings; but doesn't actually point out what OP's mistakes were.  Also, exhibiting C# code is probably not the best way to teach someone to write good Java.

Comment: C# and Java are basically the same. I mean it's not like the difference between Haskell and Java is it? And I guess I'm arguing that the OP is struggling to understand their own code to find the problems due to the fact that it's not written clearly, the intent is all over the place. Totally fair point though, I did not answer the specific question.

Comment: sorry, basically the same <> the same.